# Show $ x^4 + x^2 + 1 $ has no integer roots, but that it has a root modulo 3 and factorize it

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, congruences

Show that the following polynomial $ x^4 + x^2 + 1 $ has no integer roots, but that it has roots modulo 3, and factorize it over $ℤ_3$.

I'm not sure how to go about this problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: $$1\equiv-2\pmod3$$ and $(\pm1)^4+(\pm1)^2-2\equiv0$

Comment: Nice solution, lab. :)

Comment: Hint: why is it impossible that $x^4+x^2=-1$?

Comment: Hint: Mod $3$ we have
$$x^4+x^2+1=x^4-2x^2+1=\cdots$$

Comment: Because $\pm 1$ are roots, $x^2-1$ (or equivalently $x^2+2$) divides our polynomial. Divide, using long division. We get $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2-1)(x^2-1)$. So our polynomial factors as $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$ or equivalently as $(x+1)^2(x+2)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^4+x^2+1$ is positive since even powers of reals are non-negative and $1$ is positive.

To prove it has a root $\bmod 3$ it suffices to check the three congruence classes.